# How do I trigger a rerender in react?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

The idea is that I select an image which then gets uploaded to mongodb and in the same time as I press on upload button I want to trigger rerendering of the page so that the avatar gets updated with the newest image. To accomplish that I first send a PUT request t the server and right after that I set a local storage obejct with the values of the response.

**The functions that capture and upload the image**

```
const [reload, setReload] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {}, [reload])

const fileSelectedHandler = evt => setAvatarImage(evt.target.files[0]);

const uploadProfileImage = async evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', avatarImage);

    try {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: `${keys.SERVER_URL}/user/avatar/${isAuthenticated()._id}`, 
            data: formData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',}
        }); 

        localStorage.setItem(localStorageName, JSON.stringify({ avatar: response.data.user.avatar }));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
        setReload(prevState => !prevState);
 }
```

The thing is that the image is getting uploaded and is displayed correctly. The problem is that after I press on upload button the image is not shown instantly but I have to manually reload the page. Thats why I added that setReload. So that when I press on upload button the value of reload variable gets changed, that triggering a reload in useEffect.

Comment: For updating the profile image, we use state management which does the rerender part.

So I am assuming the picture you want to update on is navbar and where the upload component is rendered is some sort of profile edit page.

You can do it two ways.

One => use context in navbar and update the context once upload is finished.
Two => use redux

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use setState or something similar depending on your state management. localStorage does not trigger rerenders. React isn't designed that way.